# Width webpage does not fill the screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i'm writing a webpage and i can't make the div elements to full the screen.

I'm using a mac OSX and Safari, Google Chrome and Firefox browsers to view the page.

This is the my code inside the body:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.register {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 25%;
}

.FAQ {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

.sponsors {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}

.footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="register"></div>
<div class="FAQ"></div>
<div class="sponsors"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

Comment: @TemaniAfif body does have height given

Comment: @ashishsingh my mistake .. missing `width:100%` on the body

Comment: i dont think that is required

Comment: @ashishsingh he's using position:absolute, so it's if there is no content inside

Comment: whoa.. let me check how my solution was working then.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

add this line to each div

```
table-layout:fixed;
```

for example

```
.register{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 25%;
   table-layout:fixed; /* this line was added */
  }
```

Comment: it would be intresting to find the *why* of this fix :)

Comment: and what is more strange is that you don't need to add this to all the divs, only one div will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify a width to the `body` element and since you made it positioned and there is no content inside its width will by default be `0`.

As a side note, you see the grey color cover the whole screen due to [background propagation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds) and not because the `body` is already full width, so this may create confusion.

Here is the initial code with background color of `html` changed so you can clearly see that the body has `0` width:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}
html {
 background:pink;
}
body {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.register {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 25%;
  background: red;
}

.FAQ {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: blue;
}

.sponsors {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="register"></div>
<div class="FAQ"></div>
<div class="sponsors"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

And if you add `width:100%` to the body it will get fixed:

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.register {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 25%;
  background: red;
}

.FAQ {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: blue;
}

.sponsors {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background: green;
}

.footer {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25%;
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="register"></div>
<div class="FAQ"></div>
<div class="sponsors"></div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```